# Decrypting a pan number encrypted in Java using c# Using a 48 character key

Tags: c#, encryption

I have been given a card pan which is encrypted by a third party. they have used java to encrypt the pan using a key of 48 characters.

Using an online tool i can get the same result as they are seeing. but in code i am getting an "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm." error message.

Can you please advise how i can get round this issue?

code snippet below

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Text);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        TDESAlgorithm.IV = new byte[TDESAlgorithm.BlockSize / 8];
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(decrypt.Text);

        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
            Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();

        }

      decryptedText.Text =  UTF8.GetString(Results);


    }
```

code used to Encrypt below

```
public static String encryptData(String toEncrypt, byte[] sharedKeyBytes){
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[0];
    try {
        DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(sharedKeyBytes);

        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM_DESEDE).generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher encrypter = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMSATION_DESEDE_PADDED);
        encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] input = toEncrypt.getBytes(UTF_8);

        encrypted = encrypter.doFinal(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CryptoException("Exception caught when encrypting", e);
    }
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
}
```

This is the equivalent i  need to produce in c#. this code works in java

```
public static String decryptTripleDES(String toDecrypt, byte[] customerSharedKeyBytes){
    byte[] decrypted = new byte[0];

    System.out.println(customerSharedKeyBytes.length);
    try {
        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decodeBase64(toDecrypt.getBytes(UTF_8));

        DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(customerSharedKeyBytes);

        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM_DESEDE).generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher decrypter = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMSATION_DESEDE_PADDED);
        decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        decrypted = decrypter.doFinal(decodedValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CryptoException("Exception caught when decrypting", e);
    }

    return new String(decrypted);
}
```

Please advise on how to best get round this issue.

thanks

Comment: Do you have the java code that encrypts this?

Comment: I am searching for the exact encryption method from the 3rd party but all i was given for now is there were using the DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding to send us base64 string which we need to decrypt. will send the method once the third party sends it across. Thanks

Comment: thanks for advice. have now posted the code in the question

Answer (score 3):

A Triple DES key is 24 bytes long, which is 48 hexadecimal characters.

I suspect you need to hex-decode your string to get the key rather than taking the bytes of the string.

Comment: Yes, besides that, `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Text);` is normally not correct as it is incompatible with randomized key bytes. Note that the MD5 function is not used at all, and as it generates only 16 bytes, it is unlikely that you need it for keys of 24 bytes (48 hex characters).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses,

It turns out as outlined above the 3DES key needs to be 24 bytes long. I took the first 24 characters of the key and converted into the key bytes and assigned that to the 3DES key. This then worked as expected. It appears Java is forgiving compared to c# which is a bit odd. although the third party uses the 48 character key , it seems the algorithm will discard anything beyond the first 24 characters in Java BUT will not complaint or throw a run time error.

Thanks again for the responses